# Quantum model for excitation of electronic states by application of electric current/power

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electric-current, photon-emission

What is the quantum mechanical model/description for excitation of systems via application of electric power/current? Consider for example your display that you look at while you read this. The system is clearly excited by the application of electric power which leads to luminescence. Usually we treat transitions induced by photons but how are systems promoted to an excited state when electric power via a current is applied? Can we induce specific transitions or is this a "thermodynamic" process where states get populated according to a Boltzmann distribution? What is the model for this process within quantum mechanics?

Comment: What I am looking at is an LCD screen that is lit by LEDs. The process there is recombination of charge carriers. That's different from a screen lit by a gas discharge tube. Recombination in semiconductors is temperature dependent, which you can easily observe by cooling down an LED with liquid nitrogen. First it becomes much brighter (i.e. the efficiency increases) and then it dims to nothing because the charge carriers are "freezing" out. Would I call that a thermodynamic process? Not really.

Comment: @FlatterMann My knowledge of solid state physics is limited and I tend to think in a single-molecule framework with clearly defined states. The initial step in the LED should still be an excitation of a bound state which leads to the separation of the charge carrier and hole, or is this wrong? How does this initial step applying voltage work? What you describe  sounds to me what I would call the excited state dynamics which happen after the initial excitation that end by relaxation of the excited state to the ground state emitting a photon. The groundstate would be the recombined system.

Comment: It is awkward to answer your question, not because any part of the answer is hugely complicated, just because it touches many different areas and has a few different interpretations, all of which require some level of explanation, so it is difficult to avoid the answer becoming very long. If you can make the question as precise as possible and give us some idea of your background that may help cut down the answer to the essentials.

Comment: With this in mind I would add that there is a distinction between the question of "How does power get from the source to where it is used?" and "How is electrical energy converted into something directly useful?". The first of these turns out to be mainly a question of classical electromagnetism. The second, as the other commenter has hinted, turns out to vary a great deal between different types of device, even in cases where the end result may appear very similar.

Comment: There are no single molecules in LEDs. These are are all lattice phenomena and you will have to learn about classical and quantum mechanical band models, I am afraid.

Comment: Better to think in terms of applied voltage which forces electrons/holes to to increase population in areas with tuned band gaps. The small resulting current can alter the gap leading to more current flow.....

Comment: @BySymmetry I am a chemist, specialized to theoretical chemistry. I do know some basics of solid state quantum mechanics, i.e. the concept of bands, Blochs theorem.   But that is where my knowledge ends. I don't know how electric current or other processes do work within this model. The article [How Chemistry and Physics Meet in the Solid State](https://www.ch.ic.ac.uk/harrison/Group/Mallia/3year_lab_elec_str/hoffmann.pdf)  by Roald Hoffmann pretty much captures what I know.